# wcf rest service xml structure

Tags: wcf

I am using Entity framework and wcf rest service for my project. 
what i required is i want to change the xml structure which  is generated like this

```
<ArrayOfBug>
<Bug>
<BugID>1</BugID>
<PageName>Home.aspx</PageName>
<BugDescription>Bug Testing</BugD`enter code here`escription>
<Priority>H</Priority>
</Bug>
</ArrayOfBug>

-------------
```

I need Attributes instead of element like this

```
 <ArrayOfBug>
    <Bug BugID="1" PageName="Home.aspx" BugDescription="Bug Testing" Priority="H" >
    </Bug>
    </ArrayOfBug>
```

what is the best way to do so?
My interface is like this

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,  UriTemplate = "/SelectAllBug", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml )]
        List<Bug> SelectAllBug();
```

thanks in advance
Monish

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box way in WCF to do what you want.

You can extend WCF by creating a custom message formatter as shown in this [good blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx) The down-side is that you'll need to invest some time in understanding how the WCF message processing pipeline works to potentially handle formatting both the request and response messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Actually right now i am doing that only. I am getting some point that i have to inherit the 
IDispatchMessageFormatter interface and extend the functionality what i want.

Do you have any working code which can assist me more on what i want to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: This [post on implementing a formatter](http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/idispatchmessageformatter/) has more detail. It doesn't show the implementation for `CustomXmlObjectSerializer` but what you need to do is fish out the generated XML document and re-structure it so that the elements become attributes in the converted XML document. I'd implement an XSLT transformation that's specific to the operation along the lines of this [article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice i have solved that issue i have to inherit IDispatchMessageFormatter interface and override the  public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result) method thanks for your help